# How to create jinLib folder to android studio

Tags: android, android-ndk

How to add `jniLib` folder to android studio? I have tried like choosing from right click and select `JNI` folder, but can't able to create!

Comment: @AkashPatel the answers there all speak about **`jni`** folder, not **`jniLibs`**. They don't help here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no on-click menu. You can add the **jniLibs** directory manually.  By default, it is `app\src\main\jniLibs`. You can create this directory in Explorer or your favorite file manager, or from command line (`mkdir XXXX\app\src\main\jniLibs` will do).

You can create this directory without leaving Android Studio, but for that you must switch from the default **Android** view to **Project**:

[image: choosing the view]

Now find **app**/**src**/**main** and right click on it and choose **New**/**Directory**. Enter **jniLibs** as new directory name. Click **OK**.

Note that you can also use a different name for your **jniLibs** directory (that is, the directory where you can put prebuilt native (JNI) libraries that Android Studio will automatically pack into your APK). You can even have multiple directories recognized by Android Studio. This is controlled in **app/build.gradle** script:

```
android { sourceSets { main { jniLibs.srcDirs "src/main/qqq", "abc" }}}
```

Now, in **Project** view I see this:

[image: 'Project' view]

And in **Android** view the two directories are 'merged':

[image: 'Android' view]

*(I added manually empty files `abc.lib` and `qqq.lib` to make it easier to understand what is going on)*.

To use the **jniLibs** folder(s), you put there your prebuilt **.so** files, under ABI subdirectories, e.g.

[image: jniLibs inside]

Comment: thats what i expected..:)..thanks a lot @Alex Cohn ...it worked...